# R: Model results in same test accuracy and ROC - How is this possible?

Tags: keras, r

I've trained a simple mlp with my data set (unfortuanetly I cannot share any details):

```
model <- keras_model_sequential()
model %>%
  layer_dense(units = 64, activation = "relu", input_shape = c(dim(train_x)[[2]])) %>%
  layer_dropout(rate = 0.2) %>%
  layer_dense(units = 64, activation = "relu") %>%
  layer_dropout(rate = 0.2) %>%
  layer_dense(units = 1, activation = "sigmoid")


model %>% compile(
  loss = "binary_crossentropy",
  optimizer = optimizer_adam(learning_rate = 0.00005),
  metrics = c("accuracy")
)

history <- model %>% fit(
  train_x, train_y,
  epochs = 15, batch_size = 64,
  validation_split = 0.2, shuffle  = T
)

test_preds <- model %>% predict(test_x) %>% `>`(0.5) %>% k_cast("int32") %>% data.matrix()
(test_acc <- MLmetrics::Accuracy(test_preds, test_y))
(roc <- MLmetrics::AUC(test_preds, test_y))
```

This gives me:

```
> (test_acc <- MLmetrics::Accuracy(test_preds, test_y))
[1] 0.77375
> (roc <- MLmetrics::AUC(test_preds, test_y))
[1] 0.77375
```

How can this be that `Accuracy` and `AUC` gives the same value? Might this be an indication for the model predicting values either close to `0` and `1` rather than close to the decision boundary at `0.5` ?

Comment: Welcome to DataScienceSE. If I'm not mistaken, this could happen if your majority class has exactly 77% and the model always predicts this class (not 100% sure). If this happens there's a problem somewhere of course.

Comment: there is actually no majority class. In the training I use `56000` class 0 and 1 instances. For testing, `10000` of class 0 and 1

Comment: Oh wait, I just realized: it's certainly because you're giving `test_preds` to the AUC function. The AUC needs the predicted *probabilities*, not the predicted classes.

Comment: oh boy of course... - thank you man!